# Not recieving HTTP body with Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, http, server

I'm trying to build a super simple JSON-RPC server and I'm having problems receiving the body of a POST message. I can receive GET messages fine, since the arguments are just included in the Host Header. But I can't receive the body of either a POST or a PUT. I've used two different versions of Postman and cUrl to verify that I actually am sending a proper POST message.

My code is fairly simple; I create a socket, bind to it, then listen and save what's been received. (P is the reference to the Program class)

```cs
p.sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
p.sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, p.config.server_port));
p.sock.Listen(5);
p.serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => serverListen(p)));
p.serverThread.Start();
```

and then I use the following block to actually receive messages:

```
Socket recieved = p.sock.Accept();
//handle recieved info
string message = "";
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
int readResult = recieved.Receive(buffer);
if (readResult > 0) {
    message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0, readResult);
    message = message;//for debugging purposes
    message = ReceivedMessage.decodeURL(message);//Get rid of URL encoding
}
```

This works great for GET messages, but fails to return the body for POST messages. The above code retrieves the following HTTP message:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5dab0e8e-910f-4c5d-a7dd-49bf5348a8d0
Content-Type: text/plain
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/3.0.5
Accept: */* 
Host: localhost:1215
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 18
Connection: keep-alive
```

Which doesn't contain any body elements at all. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was that the HTTP headers are sent first, then the body is sent afterwards. Or at least I think that's what is happening. So in order to read the body, you have to make another call to Socket.Recieve() (or the Async version) to get the body text. Which can look like this:

```
//get the rest of the body
string httpBody = string.Empty;
byte[] bodyBuffer = new byte[10000];    //arbitrary buffer length
string[] lines = message.Split('\n');   //split the header Message by newlines
string StrLength = string.Empty;
int contentLength = 0;
foreach (string line in lines) {
    if (line.Contains("content-length")) {
        string[] splitLine = line.Split(':');
        StrLength = splitLine[1];
        break;
    }
}
if (StrLength != null) {
    try {
        contentLength = int.Parse(StrLength);
    }
    catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse content-length");
    }
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("content-length header not found");
}
int bodyReadResult = sock.Receive(bodyBuffer);
if (bodyReadResult != contentLength) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to read all of HTTP body, probably sent as a multipart");
}
httpBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bodyBuffer, 0, bodyReadResult);
```